# Nested iif statements in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, type-conversion, conditional-operator

I am attempting to write a nested iif statement in SSRS that will convert the varchar values that are numbers(isnumeric) to integer and leave the text as is. I also want to be sure if the value in the cell is "0" it will return a blank or "". Please see the code I am using below. Any insights as to why the non-numeric text is showing as #Error would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
=iif(
Fields!O1_Parent_Line_Item_ID.Value is "0", "", iif(ISNUMERIC(Fields!O1_Parent_Line_Item_ID.Value), CInt(Fields!O1_Parent_Line_Item_ID.Value), Fields!O1_Parent_Line_Item_ID.Value))
```

Comment: I think your first condition is wrong with `is`. Change this `Fields!O1_Parent_Line_Item_ID.Value is "0", ""` to `InStr(Fields!O1_Parent_Line_Item_ID.Value,"0") > 0, ""`

Comment: Thanks for your comment WEI_DBA. This helped me clarify I am not looking for the "0" values within the string to return the whole field as blank but only if a "0" is the only value in the cell should a blank be returned. I hope this helps clarify the request.

Comment: You need to check if `ISNUMERIC` returns true, so... `ISNUMERIC(Fields!O1_Parent_Line_Item_ID.Value) = 1...`

Comment: Thanks bjones but I am still receiving an #error on the blank values.

Comment: Can you show sample data and what you would expect given the condition of you `IIF` statement?

Comment: The iif function will evaluate both args at execution time. It is evil like that.  One more thing: I'm not clear about why you need to convert a string to a number and a number to a string, in the same formula.  Your formula would be simpler if you just left it as all numbers or all strings.

Comment: Why don't you use {Fields!O1_Parent_Line_Item_ID.Value = "0", "",} instead?

Comment: Check to make sure there are no null values in your dataset. Null will tend to eff with functions and return an error.

Comment: @tgolisch The column contains both numbers and blank values. The numbers are being stored as text and I am attempting to convert them without the blank cells showing as an #Error when exporting to excel.

Comment: Yes, I can see that you are converting them. I don't see why. Are you doing some math with them, like a sum or avg? Is there some reason you aren't converting nulls to zeros?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `SWITCH` statement instead of nested `IIF`s and test for non numeric first. SWITCH statements stop at the first expression that returns true.

```
=SWITCH (
    ISNUMERIC((Fields!O1_Parent_Line_Item_ID.Value), CInt(Fields!O1_Parent_Line_Item_ID.Value), 
    Fields!O1_Parent_Line_Item_ID.Value = "0", ""
    True, Fields!O1_Parent_Line_Item_ID.Value
    )
```

The above statement will test each expression in turn until it finds one that returns true. So if it's numeric, convert to `int`. If it's "0" return and empty string. If both those return false then the last expression will always return true so you will get you original value.

Note that 0 numeric values will return 0 not "" as they are obviously numeric so the first expression will catch it.